# How do you perform conditional rendering in functional components in React?

Tags: reactjs

Typically I would do this:

```
render() {
   const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
   return (
      <div>
         {isLoggedIn ? (
            <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
         ) : (
        <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
 }
```

... but obviously I can't use this code inside a functional component

```
export const LoginContainer = () { 
   {if <-- CRASH!   
}
```

What is the typically best way to deal with it?

Comment: Did you go through https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html ?

Comment: They're traditional react components (with render method) as far as I can see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if its functional component and you save loggedin status to state like this.

replace (state)true with your loggedin status

```
const [state, setState]=React.useState(true);
```

Code

```
export const LoginContainer=()=>{
  const isLoggedIn = state;
   return (
      <div>
         {isLoggedIn ? (
            <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
         ) : (
        <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You can't use a return statement inside a functional component so this wouldn't work I think?

Comment: Yep, you're right. The userState hook needs to be in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Using Fragments

```
export const LoginContainer = () => { 
  <>
   {if <-- CRASH!
  </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function component is just a function, and it can be defined via the classic `function(){}` syntax or the ES6 arrow syntax (`() => {}`).

You can use a `return` statement in ES6 arrow functions, but you don't have to. I tend to avoid them when possible in order to cut down on boilerplate.

Something along these lines should work, for instance:

```js
export const LoginContainer = ({ handleLogoutClick, handleLoginClick }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true)
  return (
    <div>
      <LogoutButton onClick={state ? handleLogoutClick : handleLoginClick} />
    </div>
  )
}
```